# Managing files in Android terminal

Tags: android, linux

Using a terminal emulator in my android phone I accidentally copied /proc directory into another user directory.  Now I want to delete the copy but I don't have the permissions to do so. I tried to change ownership and permissions to 777 but with no success.  I am using Oneplus 2 and termux application. Any suggestions?

Edit:
The original /proc directory :

```
   dr-xr-xr-x  459 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 proc/
```

it was copied to /.../line/proc:
Line:

```
drwxrwxrwx    4 u0_a45   u0_a45        4096 Oct 17 12:23 line/
```

Line/proc:

```
dr-xr-xr-x   52 u0_a45   u0_a45        4096 Jan  1  1970
```

proc/

The new proc directories are not removable:

```
rm -rf line/proc
rm: can't remove 'line/proc/12159/task/12247': Permission denied
...
```

Comment: What about rooting your device?) In any case if it doesn't make any harm leave it as is...

Comment: I know, it just bothers me because it is yelling "owner is stupid!".  Don't think I would root the device just to erase it though.

Comment: I'm not sure, but if the directory was protected then you shouldn't be able to write anything there. Give more details regarding the directory, commands, and permission error.